# A robot arm consisting of a sequence of rigid line segments L1, L2, . . . , Ln hinged together consecutively

Tags: algorithms

Hi I am a Computer Science student attempting to solve this problem for extra credit. Problem is I am unsure what this algorithm is asking for as the language is a bit hard for me to follow:

> Imagine that you have a robot arm consisting of a sequence of rigid
>   line segments $L_{1}, L_{2}, \dots , L_{n}$ hinged together
>   consecutively. The lengths of the line segments $l_{1}, l_{2}, \dots ,
> > l_{n}$ are positive integers. You may rotate freely around the hinges
>   and the line segments are allowed to cross over. Our goal is to pack
>   in the line segments into one line segment as compactly as possible.
>   More precisely, given positive integers $l_{1}, l_{2}, \dots , l_{n}$
>   (and $l_{0} = 0)$ and a sequence of
>   $\pm1$’s, $s_{0}, s_{1}, \dots , s_{n}$, where $s_{i} = 1$ or $s_{i} = −1$, $0 ≤ i ≤ n$, define
>
> $$m_1 = \min_j\left(\sum_{i=0}^j s_il_i\right) $$
>   $$m_2 = \max_j\left(\sum_{i=0}^j
> s_il_i\right) $$
>   where ($0 ≤  j ≤ n$).
>   Find $\min_s (m_{2} − m_{1})$, where the minimum is taken over all sequences
>   $s = (s_0, s_2, \dots , s_n)$.

The goal is for me to write an algorithm that solves this problem. But I am not entirely sure what the question is asking. My understanding is drawn below:
[image]

The arms shall be compacted as much as they can be such the vertical height of the extended arm is minimized. But I don't understand what the $s_0, s_1,\dots, s_n$ sequence is for? And if someone could describe in layman's terms what the sequences $m_1$ and $m_2$ are asking for that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $s$'s tell you which way each segment of the arm is pointing: $s_i=+1$ if the $i$th segment points up and $s_i=-1$ if the $i$th segment points down.

This means that $S_j := \sum_{i=0}^j s_i\ell_i$ is the distance of the end of the $i$th segment from the pivot. So $\min_j S_j$ and $\max_j S_j$ are the height of the lowest and highest points of the arm when it's folded in the way that $s_0, \dots, s_n$ describe.